# Can you change a tvOS app built using TVML without submitting an app update to Apple?

Tags: tvos, tvml

When building a tvOS app using TVML, the logic, written in Javascript is downloaded from your server, hosting the files. Does that mean that you could change the Javascript, modifying your app, without having to submit an update to Apple for review?

The tutorial I have been following is
[Beginning tvOS Development with TVML Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial).

Following the steps in the tutorial, I have successfully started a server locally that is hosting the Javascript files. I can then change part of the Javascript files and then see the change reflected in the app (after I relaunch it). This seems like evidence to me that you could make changes to the app without submitting an update to Apple for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any externally hosted files can be updated. I have personally tested this by adding content and descriptions to my tvml files.

Comment: Just for clarification, you have personally done this on an app that is live on the tvOS App Store? Not just locally on an app that is in development?

Answer (score 0):

Apple TV will obey any cache headers on the JS script that's served. Additionally, it will only completely reload the app (and the JS with it) if the app has been terminated by TVOS or the user.

Once these criteria are met, it's technically possible to deliver 'OTA' updates to your app without going through App Review again. This is fine with the App Review Guidelines for Apple TV, as long as you're not making 'significant changes' without going through review.